# Array function expression as a type

Tags: typescript

```
type Predicate = 'truthy' | 'falsy' | Function;
```

I'd like to make the 'Function' more specific but unfortunately I can't do

```
type Predicate = 'truthy' | 'falsy' | () => boolean;
```

I know that I can always do

```
someFunction(parameter: 'truthy' | 'falsy' | () => boolean) {...}
```

but I'd like to define a type with those three options. Am I able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. Due to precedence rules the function type has to be put into parentheses:

```
type Predicate = 'truthy' | 'falsy' | (() => boolean);
```

Alternatively, of course, you can also define the function type separately:

```
type BooleanFunctionPredicate = () => boolean;
type Predicate = 'truthy' | 'falsy' | BooleanFunctionPredicate;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you